# Creation of two dependent select box in php

Tags: php

I am trying to create two dependent select box in php.but it is not working properly..I am trying to retrieve data from my table names **address** which contains two column **district** and **place** ..fro **district** first select box is working but as the second select box is dependent on first select box ,there must be any problem which caused the second select box to not work properly..As a result it retrieves no data..

**here is my code in page practice.php**

```
`<?php
    function load_district()
    {
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or 
        die(mysqli_error($connect));

        mysqli_select_db($connect,"Ajmal") or die(mysqli_error($connect));

        $output='';
        $sql="SELECT DISTINCT district FROM address";
        $result=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $output .= '<option 
        value .= "'.$row["district"].'">'.$row["district"].'</option>';
    }
    return $output;
}

?>

<html>

    <head>
        <title>Ajmal Hossain</title>
        <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> 
        </script>
    </head>

<body>

    <p>Select District
        <select name="district" id="district">
            <option value="">Select District</option>
            <?php echo load_district(); ?>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>Select Place
        <select name="place" id="place">
            <option value="">Select place</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</body>
</html>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#district').change(function(){
           var district_id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url:"fetch_state.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{districtID:district_id},
                dataType:"text",

                success:function(data){
                    $('#place').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
 });
</script>`
```

**this is my PHP code on page fetch_sate.php**

```
    `<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or 
    die(mysqli_error($connect));

    mysqli_select_db($connect,"ajmal") or die(mysqli_error($connect));

    $output = '';

    $sql="SELECT place FROM address WHERE district = 
    '".$_POST["districtID"]."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

    $output = '<option value="">Select Place</option>';

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        $output = '<option 

        value .= "'.$row["place"].'">'.$row["place"].'</option>';

    }
    echo $output;
    ?>`
```

Comment: You should run this with the F12 console open to check for console errors (JavaScript bug) and use the Network tab to see the AJAX request and response (JavaScript or PHP bug).  If that does not solve the problem, edit your question to include more information.  Also, search StackOverflow "PHP errors" to see how to turn on error reporting in PHP so your AJAX response will include PHP errors.

Comment: You can also try calling the fetch_state.php page outside of AJAX (using a different HTML page with fixed values) to make sure it works.  Again, search SO if you do not know how to show PHP errors.

Comment: I didn't get u!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change

```
$('#place').html(data);
```

to

```
 $('#place').find('option').remove().append(data);
```

which will remove all the existing options and add your new ones. You also need to change this line:

```
$output = '<option value="'.$row["place"].'">'.$row["place"].'</option>';
```

to this:

```
$output .= '<option value="'.$row["place"].'">'.$row["place"].'</option>';
```

so that you don't overwrite all the options other than the last.

Comment: Have you checked what is in data?

Comment: You could use the Developer tools, set a breakpoint at the success function and then examine the variable. Or just put an `alert(data);` into the code.

Comment: I added break point and put alart function but nothing happend

Comment: After the breakpoint did you try console.log(data) in the debugger window?

Comment: showing two errors  **jquery.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)** and **practice.php:32 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at practice.php:32** practice.php line 32 is `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: **GET http://localhost/Trying/jquery.js net::ERR_ABORTED** <<<<>>>>  '**practice.php:32 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at practice.php:32**<<<<>>>>>      **Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at chrome-extension://enhgphjilbbibefkleinohgnnllpdnna/scripts/core/content.js:18:53**<<<>>>     **Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at chrome-extension://enhgphjilbbibefkleinohgnnllpdnna/scripts/core/content.js:23:42** after debuging

Comment: So then it sounds like you're not successfully loading jQuery. Are you sure jquery.js is in the same directory as practice.php? If not you will need to either copy it there or correct the path to it in the `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` tag

Comment: yeah,there is no jquery.js file in the same directory...what should be the directory??can u give me the link??actually i wrote this code from a video..they didn't give the link or file even in video description

Comment: Try this: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: yeah,it is almost done...but when i select a district from district select box , there should be multiple values in place select box..for example If i choose "Chittagong" as a district under chittagong there are 5 place in my database ..but it shows only one..what is the problem???

Comment: Did you see the edit I made a couple of hours ago? You have an error in your PHP code generating $output

Comment: Yeah, I fixed it...but no change

Comment: Can you edit your post with your current code for fetch_state.php?

Comment: You put the . in the wrong place, it should be `$output .=` not `value .=`

Comment: OH dear!!!!thank you very much...This code run perfectly...thanks a lot...

Comment: Yeah, Thanks a lot again... i posted another question ... If you can help,please give suggestion..

Comment: Sorry it looks like it's a bit outside my expertise. Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use post then the parameter is **type** and not **method**

Try with onchange event like below:

In practice.php:

```
<select name="district" id="district" onchange="get_state(this.value);">
        <option value="">Select District</option>
        <?php echo load_district(); ?>
    </select>
```

Correct the ajax syntax as below:

```
<script>
function get_state(district_id)
{
    $.ajax({
            url:"fetch_state.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{districtID:district_id},
            success:function(data){
                $('#place').html(data);
            }
        });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Only for jQuery before 1.9.0. Since then it has been [method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: In developer tools its showing error in line no 32 `$(document).ready(function(){`    that practice.php:32 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Plz check the edited answer and try. I hope it help you to solve your issue.

Comment: the problem is not with the district select box..it works fine..problem occured in select box place ...it doesn't load place..I think there is problem in js code...in developer tools showing erro at line `$(document).ready(function(){` saying **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined**

Comment: Yes that is why I am asking you to remove the $(document).ready(function(){ function and use the above code in which there is no need to use the document function. Please verify the jquery loaded correctly or not.

Comment: if replace the above code from where the function get_state() will get its parameter district_id? and it want to say that `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` not loading

Comment: Inside district select box I pass this.value. So district_id will pass from there.

Answer (score 0):

please pass district  id in option value:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $output .= '<option 
        value="'.$row["district"].'">'.$row["district"].'</option>';
   }
```